# Why does ggarrange produce a different result than it used to (legend illegible and misalignment due to common y-axis label)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have six plots that I arrange in two columns and three rows using ggarrange, with a common legend and a common y-axis title. My code used to produce the desired output just fine, but now I replotted it, and suddenly, the legend is scrambled because the two groups overlap. In addition, my solution for creating a common y-axis label (which, admittedly, was a bit cobbled-together but used to work, too!) now leads to misalignment in the y-axes in the left column. Below is a reproducible example. Can someone point me to possible solutions?

```
require( tidyverse)
require( grid)
require( ggpubr)
require( extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")


list(type = rep( c( "(1)", "(2)", "(3)", "(4)","(5)", "(6)"), each = 16), 
     group = rep( rep( c("First Group", "Second Group"), each = 8), 6),  
     x = rep( c(-7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7), times = 12),
     scale_x = c(0.087, 0.085, 0.083, 0.081, 0.079, 0.077, 0.075, 0.073, 
                 0.087, 0.085, 0.083, 0.081, 0.079, 0.077, 0.075, 0.073, 
                 -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 
                 -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 
                 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 
                 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 
                 77, 75, 73, 71, 69, 67, 65, 63,
                 77, 75, 73, 71, 69, 67, 65, 63, 
                 -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 
                 -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 
                 8.49, 8.51, 8.53, 8.55, 8.57, 8.59, 8.61, 8.63, 
                 8.49, 8.51, 8.53, 8.55, 8.57, 8.59, 8.61, 8.63), 
     y = rep( c( rep( c(-0.7), times = 4), rep( c( 0.7), times = 4),
                 rep( c(-0.77), times = 4), rep( c( 0.77), times = 4)),
              times = 6))  %>% as_tibble() -> df


function_graph <- function(data){   
  data %>%
    ggplot( aes( x = x, y = y, col = group)) +
    geom_line( aes( group = interaction( group))) +
    geom_point(  position = position_dodge( width = .2)) + 
    geom_vline( xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c( "red", "black")) +
    scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq( -1, 1, length.out = 6)) +
    coord_cartesian( ylim = c(-1, 1), xlim = c( 7, -7)) +
    geom_text( aes( label = "left"), 
               y = .95, x = 3.5, size = 3, col = "gray36", family = "Palatino Linotype") +
    geom_text( aes( label = "right"), 
               y = .95, x = -3.5, size = 3, col = "gray36", family = "Palatino Linotype")
}

# Graph (1)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(1)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(1)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (1)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_1

# Graph (2)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(2)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(2)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (2)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_2

# Graph (3)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(3)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(3)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (3)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_3

# Graph (4)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(4)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(4)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (4)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_4

# Graph (5)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(5)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(5)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (5)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_5

# Graph (6)
df %>%
  filter( grepl( "(6)", type)) %>%
  select( scale_x) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct( scale_x) %>%
  arrange( scale_x) %>%
  as_vector -> x_labels

df %>%
  filter( grepl("(6)", type)) %>%
  function_graph() +
  labs( x = "Unit for graph (6)", y = "Common y-axis label") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = rev(seq(-7, 7, length.out = 8)),
    labels = x_labels
  ) -> p_6

require( grid)
require( ggpubr)
theme_own <- function(){
  theme_minimal() %+replace%  
    theme( plot.caption = element_text(
      color="black",  size = 11,
      hjust = 1),
      axis.title = element_text(  
        size = 9),
      axis.text = element_text(    
        size = 7),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,
                              face="bold",
                              size=13,
                              vjust = 2),
      text = element_text( family = "Palatino Linotype" ),
      legend.position="bottom",
      legend.title = element_blank()
    )
}
ggarrange(p_1 + theme_own() + rremove("ylab") , 
          p_2 + theme_own() + rremove("ylab"), 
          p_3 + theme_own(), 
          p_4 + theme_own() + rremove("ylab"),
          p_5 + theme_own() + rremove("ylab"),
          p_6 + theme_own() + rremove("ylab"),
          ncol=2, nrow=3, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom") %>%
  annotate_figure( top = text_grob("A nice title", 
                                   color = "black", face = "bold", size = 14,
                                   family = "Palatino Linotype" ))
```

[image]

Comment: My hunch is that it is related to the code, perhaps due to theme options or a bug with ggarrange. Can you please provide a reproducible example? It will be hard to help without one.

Comment: @JonSpring, I've updated the question to include a reproducible example. Thanks for bearing with me.